# Unable to reset store values

Tags: svelte-3, svelte-store

I would like to reset an existing store's values to the defaults. For UX reasons, I don't want to create a new store.

```js
const defaults = {
  name: {
    value: "",
  },
  foo: [],
  some: {
    other: {
      data: ""
    }
  }
};
const store = writable(defaults);

export const myStore = {
  subscribe: store.subscribe,
  reset: () => {
    store.set(defaults);
  }
};
```

The store behaves as expected, with the exception of the `reset()` method. Whenever it's called it does not update the store, none of the reactive bindings reflect what should be the default values.

```js
...
$myStore.name.value = "foo";
// foo
myStore.reset();
$myStore.name.value;
// foo
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an issue with Svelte, but with how javascript handles objects. When you assign an object to another variable, it will only assign a reference, and not clone the object. This means that, when you call `$myStore.name.value = "foo";`, you are actually updating the same object that is stored in `defaults`.

You can observe this by running the code below

```js
let a = {name: ''};
let b = a;
b.name = 'test';
console.log(a); // {name: 'test'}
```

Since you're using objects inside objects, just destructuring default also won't work, since you'll only get a shallow copy of an object, meaning that you could update `$myStore.name` but wouldn't be able to update `$myStore.name.value` properly.

To properly copy defaults, you could use [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone), which is available in Chrome 98, Firefox 94 and Node 17. Rewriting your code, it would be something like this:

```js
const store = writable(structuredClone(defaults));

export const myStore = {
  subscribe: store.subscribe,
  reset: () => {
    store.set(structuredClone(defaults));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way -

```
const defaults = {
  name: {
    value: "",
  },
  foo: [],
  some: {
    other: {
      data: ""
    }
  }
};
const store = writable(defaults);

export const myStore = {
  subscribe: store.subscribe,
  reset: () => {
    store.set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(defaults)));
  }
};
```